# Combobox value null on first launch

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

When my app launches I get null on first launch from combobox, but when I change it I get the right result on launch

```
    public partial class MainScreen : Page
    {
        SQLReader sql;

        public MainScreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            sql = new SQLReader();
            List<string> st = sql.getQuery("SELECT Name FROM Positions");

            PrCombo.ItemsSource = st;
            PrCombo.SelectedIndex = 0;

        }

        private void PrCombo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string st = PrCombo.Text; //is null when the app starts

        }


    }
```

Comment: `string st = PrCombo.Text; //is null when the app starts` - of course, it's in the `SelectionChanged` event. Explain what your end goal is?

Comment: To read PrCombo (combobox) data

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.selectionchangedeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try access to selected item except of combobox text.

```
string st = PrCombo.SelectedItem.ToString();
```